# How to group sentences of identical characters in python ( 'aabcdd' -> ['aa', 'b', 'c', 'dd'] )?

Tags: python

I have a string `'aabbababacccssdd'` from which I want to generate `['aa', 'bb', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'ccc', 'ss', 'dd']`

Here's my present solution:

```
def get_pats(n):
    n = str(n) # to support integers
    a = len(n)
    p = []
    pat_start = 0
    prev = 0
    for b in range(0, a):
        if n[b] != n[prev]:
            p.append(n[pat_start:b])
            prev = b
            pat_start = b
    p.append(n[pat_start:b+1])
    return p
```

The solution works good enough, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant/pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) does for you:

```
text = 'aabbababacccssdd'

from itertools import groupby
print [''.join(g) for k, g in groupby(text)]
# # ['aa', 'bb', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'ccc', 'ss', 'dd']
```